# Функция онлайн

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую функцию.

Если пользователь не изменял информацию в бд в течении пяти минут,
то обновить столбик в таблице online на 0, где имя ровно `session['username']`,
если не так, то вывести его имя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Simple users online class (SimOnline)](http://www.sim-php.info/users-online-script.php). Гугл мне быстро ответил :)